# Will holding in your sneeze kill brain cells?

Tags: biology, physiology

I heard from a friend that holding in your sneeze can actually kill a few of your brain cells. I did a google search, but most of the results had no evidence (e.g. [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100219184948AADKMBj)). Moreover, I checked out [Snopes](http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=42;t=000234;p=1), but it was more of the same.

Are there any scientific studies or evidence that supports what my friend says?

Comment: I have heard of damage occurring to the inner ear (resulting in loss of balance). I only mention this because you may be looking for a slightly different phenomenon than you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Holding in a sneeze is a form of involuntary Valsalva manoeuvre.  In a Valsalva, there are characteristic changes in cerebral blood flow, and velocity as reported in this study [1]

> The characteristic changes in blood pressure (phases I to IV) were
>   seen in all subjects, accompanying distinct changes in cerebral blood
>   flow velocity. The relative changes in mean velocity during phases II
>   and IV were significantly greater than those in mean blood pressure.
>   Compared with the baseline value, velocity decreased by 35% in phase
>   IIa, then rose by 56.5% in phase IV (corresponding changes in blood
>   pressure were -10.2% and +29.8%, respectively).

So, it is conceivable that in people with some weakening in intracranial blood vessels eg. an aneurysm, a stroke might result with aneurysm rupture.

Alan Wild, a head and neck surgeon and assistant professor of otolaryngology at Saint Louis University School of Medicine, is quoted as saying holding in a sneeze in an unlucky person might: [2]

> ...weaken a blood vessel in the brain and cause it to rupture due to
>   the momentary elevation of blood pressure

but otherwise, if you don't have such anatomical variations, then there is no mechanism to *kill a few brain cells*.

[1] Tiecks FP, Lam AM, Matta BF, Strebel S, Douville C, Newell DW. [Effects of the valsalva maneuver on cerebral circulation in healthy adults. A transcranial Doppler Study.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7631342) Stroke. 1995 Aug;26(8):1386-92. PubMed PMID: 7631342.

[2] http://www.livescience.com/32776-is-it-safe-to-hold-in-a-sneeze.html